# One entire single file as a record to a Mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

What are the available options and best practices for this scenario : passing a single file as an input to a mapper or rephrasing it - a mapper processing an entire file as a single record. Like in default case a mapper is invoked for every record/line but how to process/pass an entire file as a record

By reading I came across several options :

- Sequence files : as it's good for large no. Of smaller files which can be compressed and zipped together and then key will be filename and value will be actual zip file.
- CombinefileInput format : this is one way I came across and also WholeFileInputFormat . But the whole file input format extends the CombinefileInputformat only.
- IsSplittable() : I also came across this method where the IsSplittable is overridden in the setup method of a mapreduce program.

Now which should be used when or what is the best practice for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

CombinefileInput format : This is useful when you have large number of small files , in this case if we don't use CombineFileInput format ,then even for a very small size files , each files will correspond to one split that means one mapper would be there for each small file so lots of mappers would be running and would be taking unnecessarily resources of your clusters.

Is Splittable : In this scenario if you have large file it won't break into multiple splits  and it would go to one mapper but there won't be any parallelism but this would solve that purpose sending one big file to one mapper.

If you want to send a complete file a one record in that case you will have to customize your own  record reader , by default it breaks one record when ever it detects '\n' in your file so if you want to send complete file in one record you will have to override the above functionality by writing logic based on total number of bytes rather than \n.